# Access x-requestid in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

Please see the code below:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePerson([FromBody]CreatePersonCommand command, [FromHeader(Name = "x-requestid")] string requestId)
{
    ..
}
```

This is a web api method, which is accessed by another project.

The client code looks like this:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(uri, personContent);
```

Is it possible to access the x-requestid at the client in the response that is sent from the web api project?

Comment: The wording of the last sentence has me a little confused. can you clarify

Comment: Are you asking if you can get the header value in the `response` object?

Comment: @MarkC. I am uncertain of that as well.

Comment: @Mark C, yes.  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: In case you are trying to get it from response, the answer would be yes, but only if the web api populates it in the response. I assume that since the web api tries to bind to it that it was included in the request. It will only be in the response if the web pi adds it.

Comment: @Nkosi, how would I access it on the client? response.Headers.something    ?

Comment: Yes from the headers. but note my comment about how it would be populated.

Comment: Does the web api have some middleware that adds that header?

Comment: @ Nkosi, the client has middleware to add the x-requested, however the web api does not.  I will try adding the middleware to the web api and get back to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your `HttpClient` comes from `System.Net.Http`.

In case you need to get value:

```
var response = await _httpClient.PutAsync(uri, personContent);

response.Headers.TryGetValues("x-requestid", out var headerValues);
```

If you need to add headers to the response in your Web API, you have access to `Response` entity in your controller which inherits from ASP `ControllerBase` class:

```
Response.Headers.Add("x-requestid", "value");
```

Comment: How would I add x-requested to the response from the web api? I added it to the request from the MVC client by creating a HttpClientRequestIdDelegatingHandler class.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you add the header to the response in the web api.  I assume that I have to create a class, which extends something?

Comment: @w0051977 check for the update again. Sorry your question was a bit unclear from the beginning